# How to mimic ActionFilter Attribute in Asp.net web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

In MVC user can use action filter like this:

```
[Log]
ActionResult Home()
{
     return View();
}
```

Now I am going to find equivalent for ActionFilter in asp.net web form. How I can mimic that like above for asp.net web form and apply them to event handlers?

```
[Log]
protect void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do some operations here
}
```

**Update:**

To clarify my question (As comment says my question is a little ambiguous), I want to log start of method and ending of method. In Mvc I can create Action Filter like this:

```
public class LogAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Logging start of method.
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Logging end of method.
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at custom attributes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8.aspx

Comment: Unless there are such attributes in WebForms (or any framework thereof), I imagine you're going to have to write your own.  In which case the harder part isn't going to be making the attribute, but *using* the attribute somewhere.

Comment: @David So any equivalent for that?

Comment: may be using HttpModules or Handlers..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner I need a trick to simulate that in asp.net.

Comment: if you want to log every start and ending of method, you can refer the  ASP.NET lifecycle events and override them..even I am not sure, just giving some hint..

Comment: @dotNETbeginner, Events are some example. I want to log every function in my aspx page.